# How to merge two branches on remote repos

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a remote repo. It has four branches i.e. master, branch1, branch2, branch3. I pushed changes to master repo. Now I want to add those changes to branch3. Do I have to merge them If yes then how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just

```
git checkout branch3
git rebase master
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first make sure you are in sync with your remotes:

```
checkout master
pull origin master
checkout branch3
pull origin branch3
```

then do the merge

```
merge master
```

then push if you need to

```
push origin branch3
```